# How GIL works with Multi threaded server?

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

In CPython environment, One thread does not acquire GIL from another thread, unless it is blocked(say using `sleep()`) or on IO

In below server code,

```
# server.py
import socket
import sys
from threading import Thread

def echoHandler(conn, addr):
    try:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(16) # Blocking call
            if data:
                print(data.decode('utf-8'))
                conn.sendall(data)
            else:
                break
    finally:
        print('Closing the connection from server')
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost', 10006)
    sock.bind(server_address)
    sock.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        t = Thread(target=echoHandler, args=(conn, addr))
        t.daemon = True
        t. start()
        print('Waiting for another conn')
```

---

```
#client.py
import socket
import pdb

# pdb.set_trace()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost', 10006)
    print('connecting to', server_address)
    sock.connect(server_address)

    while True:
        try:
            message = input().encode('utf-8')
        except EOFError:  #EAFP
            print('Breaking ')
            break
        sock.sendall(message)
        data = sock.recv(16) # Blocking call
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    print('close the socket')
    sock.close()
```

---

**Question:**

When does one thread get the chance to acquire GIL from another thread to serve client? Is `conn.recv(16)`, allowing server to behave multi threaded?

Comment: "In CPython environment, One thread does not acquire GIL from another thread, unless it is blocked(say using sleep) or on IO" - what makes you think that?

Comment: Waiting for network, which is most of what a server like this typically does, *is* being blocked on IO.

Comment: @user2357112 **Example 1:** [this](https://github.com/shamhub/python_programming/blob/master/2_Python%20Standard%20Library/22_Concurrency/performance/usingThreads.py) program works as sequential code without `sleep()`. `end-start` output tells that  **Example 2:** Above code in query, thread1 release GIL on `recv()`. This makes me think that

Comment: The `end-start` value printed doesn't imply that the program executes sequentially, and it certainly doesn't imply that GIL releases only happen when threads are blocked or performing I/O.

Comment: @user2357112 `t1` CPU bound thread takes the provided CPU time slice and never give up GIL, until it completes, or until n opcodes complete execution.Then `t2` takes the provided CPU time slice. main thread is anyways blocked. This is how I call it sequential

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the GIL is not held during `conn.recv(16)` (which is, after all, network I/O).

It's also periodically released (pre-2010, every 100 opcodes; more recently, on a configurable 5ms interval) to avoid thread starvation.

Comment: That's up to the OS scheduler. Nothing in Python enforces either way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Where in the source code is this 5ms configurable interval, do you know?

Comment: Because [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iG6fr81xHKA&t=180s), he says, GIL prevents multi-core concurrency.

Comment: @overexchange, it does (mostly, with some exceptions -- such as C libraries that explicitly release the GIL before doing CPU-intensive operations that don't interact with native Python datastructures), but just because you aren't using multiple cores **concurrently** doesn't mean you aren't using multiple cores. A timeslice on core 1 and a timeslice on core 2 one after the other aren't concurrent, but are still timeslices on two different cores.

Comment: How can I verify this?

Comment: Verify what, exactly? I've made a number of different assertions. Be specific.